# Keydown event in google's form input field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to listen on keydown event on search input field in google's search box
but when I type 'enter' key I can't see any output. Is there any way to handle this?

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

Comment: well they probably have an event and catch it and do not let it propagate to the window.

Comment: Please provide the input tag you have (HTML) and we'll can help you

Comment: @epascarello You're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

Window doesn't leason for keydown event you have to attach it to your input

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keydown',(e) => {
  console.log(e.which)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: It's not true. You can check it by attaching keydown event to search bar above :P

Comment: That's what I am saying.. what is an search bar..??

Answer (score -1):

You need check your event, if keydown (example) "Enter" and focus on input, then console.log(e.target.value); // for see your value.

Comment: please call handler on document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => { console.log(e.target)});